# Remove a substring after a substring

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string, for example

```
"blabla{code}<br />blabla{code}<br />bla{code}<br />"
```

How to remove all entries of `<br />` after {code}?

I've tried this:

```
    public string removeBR(string comment)
    {
        Regex codeRegex = new Regex("{code}<br />", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        return codeRegex.Replace(comment, new MatchEvaluator(m =>
        {
            string value = m.Groups[0].Value;
            return value.Remove(value.Length - 6);
        }));
    }
```

It works but is there any easier way?

Comment: string tmp ="blabla{code}<br />blabla{code}<br />bla{code}<br />";
tmp.Replace("<br />", String.Empty);

Comment: why not just comment.Replace("{code}<br />", "{code}")  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
string input = "blabla{code}<br />blabla{code}<br />bla{code}<br />";
string output = input.Replace("{code}<br />", "{code}");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

as [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Comment: OMG, how I can forget about it?) Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `string.Replace` should solve this.

```
string input = @"blabla{code}<br />blabla{code}<br />bla{code}<br />";
string result = input.Replace("{code}<br />", "{code}");
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just forgot that I can do it with a simple string.Replace

Comment: @DimaTrygodko string.Replace is more lightweight compared to RegEx in this case. (better performance)